# How to send bitcoins from one address to another without wallet

Tags: address, sendtoaddress

I generated btc address and put some coins into it. Now I want to send coins to another address. I can't find any infomation about how I can do it. I don't have wallet, I only have address: public key and private key.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your private key, you are able to import it into a wallet and send the coins from there. The trustless way to do this would be to start your very own Bitcoin and user the [Import Private Key](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importprivkey) RPC call. You then would be able to use the [Send To Address](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#sendtoaddress) RPC call to send the coins.

Depending on your necessary security level, it may be easier to just use an online wallet service like [BTC.com](https://wallet.btc.com/#/setup/register). They have instructions available for importing private keys as well: https://help.btc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002934354-How-do-I-import-my-private-key-into-the-wallet-

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tell me please, why it is a trustless way to use bitcoin core? I thought it is the most trusted way)

Comment: @Oleg: By trustless mkaplan means without the need to trust intermediaries. Bitcoin was designed to be trustless in this sense. Trustless is different from untrusted or untrustworthy.